# Regex replace everything that not match

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following code in JS

```
function validateNumber(event) {
    $(this).val($(this).val().replace(new RegExp("[^0-9]{1,2}(\\,[^0-9]{1,2})?$", "gm"), ""));
};

$("#panel-links").on("keyup", "[name=quantidade]", validateNumber);
```

I want to remove any letters and the float value must have 2(length),2(length).

Comment: Could you provide us with some input and expected output. Thanks

Comment: Of course, 22d,3 equals 22,3, or A equals (empty string), 12 equals 12, need to remove anything that's not a number and my separator for float is ,

Comment: Instead of removing, why not match the floats?

Comment: I match on the final validation( on server), but I want to remove from input any caracters that not match my regex, after the key is pressed. I send the information on the input to server 0,5 seconds after the input lose focus.

Comment: But if you have `22d,3` and `12` in 1 input, then the number will be 22,312 right? or do you want to keep the space in between?

Comment: These are different values that can be on the input, just for exemple.

Comment: Perhaps `[^\d,]+|,\D|\D,|\d+,\d{3}|\d{3,}(?:,\d+)?` see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/dAYZoo/1/)

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thank you very much!

Comment: @MatheusZenker This is a slightly updated version, but chances are  that I might have missed some edge cases https://regex101.com/r/3McnAr/1

Comment: Why not replace all non-digit values and, use `parseFloat` and `toFixed`? Also `return false` when the outcome is `NaN` with `isNaN`.

Answer (score 0):

> Perhaps [^\d,]+|,\D|\D,|\d+,\d{3}|\d{3,}(?:,\d+)? see demo  [The fourth bird](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5424988/the-fourth-bird)